# Recursively rename files to ASCII Standard

Tags: linux, bash, recursion, mv

So we have a problem where we need to crawl through hundreds of thousands of images and rename all of them to comply with ASCII standards. After doing a lot of research online, we found this handy piece of code:

```
mv 'file' $(echo 'file' | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g')
```

sourced from: [How to remove invalid characters from filenames](https://serverfault.com/questions/348482/how-to-remove-invalid-characters-from-filenames)

I have tried merging it into a recursive find command, to be run whilst in our main images directory:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 mv $(echo | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g')
```

But i cant seem to get it to run. The closest i've gotten, is the above code throwing a lot of "mv: target `filename` Is not a directory"

So can anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this would be better:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'for f do d=${f%/*} b=${f##*/} nb=${b//[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_}; [[ $b = "$nb" ]] || echo mv "$f" "$d/$nb"; done' _ {} +
```

`find` will find all files (`-type f`), pass them as positional arguments to this Bash snippet:

```
for f do
    d=${f%/*} b=${f##*/} nb=${b//[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_}
    [[ $b = "$nb" ]] || echo mv "$f" "$d/$nb"
done
```

We split the filename into dirname `d` and basename `b`. We use parameter expansions to replace all the unwanted characters with underscores and save that expansion into variable `nb`. We check that the expansions `$b` and `$nb` are distinct (so as to avoid an error with `mv`), and if they are distinct, perform the renaming.

I left `echo` so that nothing is actually performed, the commands are only echoed. Remove the `echo` if it looks good.

Note that this can overwrite files, e.g., files `a&b` and `a_b`.

Comment: Are you sure this is entirely Valid? The script supposedly takes 3 secs to run on a good 300+K images ..

Also should point out there are no images in the current directory, it just contains a lot of subfolders and those in turn hold the images

Comment: @amartin: the only thing I can think of is a locale problem (your character range `A-Za-z` can include characters like `é`). Try to prepend `LC_ALL=C` to the find command. Otherwise, it would be interesting if you could pinpoint specific filenames that didn't get renamed.

Comment: Prepending LC_ALL=C seemed to fix all the naming errors!! And it only taken a few seconds to iterate through a few hundred thousand images...

Comment: Lightning quick solution.. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Put this in a shell script, say fixname.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

dir=$(dirname "$1")
name=$(basename "$1")

newname=$(echo "$name" | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g')
if [ "$name" != "$newname" ]; then
    if [ ! -e "$newname" ]; then
        mv "$1" "$dir/$newname"
    else
        echo >&2 "$newname already exist for $1"
    fi
fi
```

Then use find like so:

```
find . -type f -exec sh fixname.sh {} \;
```

Comment: Didnt work for some reason - It ran, however python is still throwing: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 80: ordinal not in range(128) on the images im operating on