# Using unix rename to keep arbitrary digits

Tags: regex, linux

I've been having problems with renaming a group of files, which end with a `?` question mark.

My files look like:

```
eufk_B737?
.
.
.
```

I have no idea what that question mark means, but using rename to remove the last character, it doesn't work.

How would I do something like this:

```
...... -a.k.a 6 arbitrary characters +
digit of arbitrary length? (to get rid of the ? mark)
```

example input:

```
4lg9_A125?
```

example output:

```
4lg9_A125
```

MIND THAT ? REPRESENTS LESS READABLE CHARACTER AND NOT ?

thanks.

Comment: Please add exact input and expected output.

Comment: [how-to-remove-invalid-characters-from-filenames](http://serverfault.com/questions/348482/how-to-remove-invalid-characters-from-filenames)

Comment: Removing invalid characters worked thanks!

Comment: [recursively-rename-files-to-ascii-standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055869/recursively-rename-files-to-ascii-standard)

Comment: No Problem don't forget to search next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in *; do mv -v $file $(echo $file | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]//g'); done
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The question mark apparently represents something different than ?, therefore regex should be build from start on i guess.

Comment: The `?` might be shown in place of something less readable, so trying to match it literally may not work.

Comment: Oh...so is it like a non-printable character or something? Sorry, i did not realize that from the question. Please edit your question to clarify that...every answer is based on the fact that it is a literal `?`

Comment: It throws me no such file or directory if I use  mv -v 4lg9_A125\? 4lg9_A125..

Comment: Yes, that's the word, I will rephrase question.

Comment: Does replacing `${file%\?}` with `${file:(-1)}` work for you? like `mv -v $file ${file:(-1)}`

Comment: Edited with regex now.

Comment: This is a duplicate question lets not try to answer these and mark them as duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `find` command to find the respective files and then execute the `mv` command upon each of them:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*\?" -exec sh -c "echo {} | sed 's/\?$//' | xargs mv {}" \;
```

How it works:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*\?"` - finds all files ending in the current directory only (non-recursive)

`-exec sh -c "..."`  - for each file, executes the respective code

`echo {} | sed 's/\?$//' | xargs mv {}` - remove the `?` from the end of the file and rename the old file (`{}`)